# DRC Vehicle controller does not respond or responds very slowly in DRCSim 2.3

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,
I have upgraded to DRCSim 2.3 and since then I can't seem to control the DRC vehicle, aka the polaris ranger.
I used to operate the vehicle by:
rostopic pub /drc_vehicle/gas_pedal/cmd std_msgs/Float64 "{data X.X}"

When the vehicle is in motion, and after applying "data 0.0" the vehicle doesn't seem to stop.

In addition, the steering process takes a lot of time to turn.

Any ideas how to improve?

Oded

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2254/drc-vehicle-controller-does-not-respond-or-responds-very-slowly-in-drcsim-2.3/) by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-08**:
I have verified the behavior on my machine and am looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have created an issue on the drcsim issue tracker and assigned it to myself. https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/176

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1